# How to get nested JSON values in a MariaDB column?

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I'm saving the languages of my users within a column in JSON, e.g.:

`[{"value":"german","id":"DE"},{"value":"italian","id":"IT"}]`

How can I select/extract all values as rows via SQL from MariaDB, so that the result looks like:

```
[Languages]
german
italian
....
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use seperated table for languages and then map many to many relationship with users ?

Comment: it was just an example to keep it simple :) it is required as described

Comment: Just process this data in your backend programming language: PHP, JavaScript, or whatever your using.

Comment: This can be easily achived using a stored SQL Function in MySQL(MariaDB).

Comment: @ThilinaLakshan do you let me know the query for it? ;)

Comment: Which mariadb version you are using ?

Comment: @ThilinaLakshan MariaDB 10.4.17